# Would the term 'blue collar worker' be understood by a global audience?

Tags: editing

Would the term 'blue collar worker' be understood by a global audience, for example in India, China, Japan?

Comment: This needs context. Is this a work of fiction where one character says to another "I heard her daughter is dating some sort of blue collar worker" or a report on demographics, a piece of advertising copy, an academic thesis, ... ? How important is it to the reader to understand the phrase and what opportunity do you have to provide context or otherwise explain it if an English-speaker from a non-European culture doesn't happen to know it?

Comment: The term does not exist in Sweden... if that is any help.

Comment: If this is a work which is going to be read in English, it's reasonable to assume that the reader is familiar with this term. If this work is supposed to be translated, translator will choose a more appropriate term.